# delete google instance programatically

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am using the command:

`gcloud compute instances delete instance1 --zone="europe-west1-c"`

```
The following instances will be deleted. Any attached disks configured
 to be auto-deleted will be deleted unless they are attached to any
other instances or the `--keep-disks` flag is given and specifies them
 for keeping. Deleting a disk is irreversible and any data on the disk
 will be lost.
 - [instance1] in [europe-west1-c]

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?
```

It is asking for interactive mode Y/N but I wanted that command to be non-interactive, so do the code can work without any interaction, I did not find anything on the [google doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/delete).

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--quiet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use -q or -- quiet flag

```
gcloud compute instances delete instance1 --zone="europe-west1-c" -q
```